# Video popup for iframe isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to have a video player popup showing up when an image is clicked. I don't want the player embedded on the page and visible by default.

HTML:

```
<a href="#popupVideo" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class=
    "ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline"><img class="..." src="...chuck.jpg"></a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupVideo" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="a" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content">
       <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/41135183?portrait=0" width="497" height="298"seamless=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Javascript is over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x0xqo4nj/)

Answer (score 0):

Here i have a function called EventHandlers that will add the eventlistener to every element with the class name Vids. The ID of each video will be used to set the iframe src.

Example

```
http://player.vimeo.com/video/41135183?portrait=0
```

ID = 41135183 for this Video. 
Your image ID should be set to the video ID you want to play.

You will need to add your own styles but the functionality is all here and working.

I hope this helps, if it does please make sure to mark the question as answered.
Thanks.

```
    <script>
function EventHandlers(){
document.getElementById("ExtVid").addEventListener("click",function(event){CloseVid();},false);
//Set events for all images with the class Vids
Vids=document.getElementsByClassName('Vids');
for(var i=0;i<Vids.length;i++){
  Vids[i].addEventListener("click",function(event){VideoDisplay(event);},false);
}
}
function VideoDisplay(e){
//Check & remove Iframe.
if(document.getElementById('VidFrame')){
    console.log("removing Video Frame");
    var VidFrame=document.getElementById('VidFrame');
    VidFrame.parentNode.removeChild(VidFrame);
}
    //Buile the Iframe
    var VidID=e.target.id;
    var target = document.getElementById('VideoPopup');
    var element = document.createElement('iframe');
        element.setAttribute('id', 'VidFrame');
        element.setAttribute('src', 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+VidID+'?portrait=0');
        element.setAttribute('height', '298');
        element.setAttribute('width', '497');
        element.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
        target.appendChild(element);
document.getElementById("VideoPopup").style.display="inline";
}
function CloseVid(){
if(document.getElementById('VidFrame')){
    console.log("removing Video Frame");
    var VidFrame=document.getElementById('VidFrame');
    VidFrame.parentNode.removeChild(VidFrame);
}
document.getElementById("VideoPopup").style.display="none";
}
</script>

<body onload="EventHandlers();">
<img class="Vids" id="41135183" src="#"/>
<img class="Vids" id="41135181" src="#"/>
<img class="Vids" id="41135176" src="#"/>
<div id="VideoPopup" style="display:none;height:100%;width:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:10;background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);">
<iframe id="VidFrame"></iframe>
<button id="ExtVid" style="position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;"> Close Video </button>
</div>
</body>
```